# Spin Foam Introductory Texts

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity, loop-quantum-gravity

What are some good introductory texts on spin foams / LQG for someone specialized in SUSY / string models? I’m somewhat familiar with some of the literature (Topological Amodel and crystal melting / spin foam, Kodama state / chern simons theory, quantum dimer / quiver gauge theory, etc.) but have never fully embraced the subject.

Any references are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[Lectures on Loop Quantum Gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0210094) is the best source that I can possible recommend for someone familiar with the crystal melting description of the A model (and related combinatorial stuff).